# settings.getSettings() callback is not invoked on connector save

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I have a connector configuration page set up to create a sample connector. It looks like I can successfully save the connector, but I'm unable to retrieve the generated webhook URL. Here's a sample of the code:

```
const getSettingsHandler = (settings) => {
  document.getElementById("url").innerText = settings.webhookUrl;
};

const saveHandler = (event) => {

  microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings(settings);
  microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings(getSettingsHandler);
  event.notifySuccess();

};
```

Yet, I don't see the URL printed to the screen. It seems like `getSettingsHandler()` is not being invoked as expected. I thought maybe the issue was that the config screen closes immediately after calling `event.notifySuccess()`, before the callback is invoked. But all of the examples I've looked at use this pattern, including an official Teams project [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/blob/master/TeamsToDoAppConnector/Views/Connector/Setup.cshtml). Why isn't this callback being invoked?

Comment: Can you please check what is the value you are getting in settings.webhookurl? Please look at this [sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/blob/master/TeamsToDoAppConnector/Views/Connector/Setup.cshtml) for reference

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT That's exactly the problem, I'm trying to get that but can't because the callback function isn't being invoked. I used that sample as a reference when creating my config page.

Comment: Could you please try the [To Do connector](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/blob/master/TeamsToDoAppConnector/Views/Connector/Setup.cshtml) sample?

Comment: I have the same problem. The callback from getSettings() is not called in the popout content window in my case. The getSettings() function is available, takes a callback as argument but it never calls the callback (no success, no failure).